# Strange behavior of ParallelTable

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

I was trying to carry out the following calculations:

```
j = 0; SetSharedVariable[j];
resultlist1 = ParallelTable[j++; GaussianPotential[fieldlist[[ind2]], theta1, vz, v2, matrixsize, DisorderRangeRatio -> 0], {ind2, 1, num}];
```

At the same time, I am monitoring the progress by executing

```
Dynamic[Refresh[TableForm[{"ind1=", ind1, "ind2=", ind2, "j=", j}], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

There are two strange things:

(1) The behavior of j. The second command just quickly updates j from 1 to num, and stops there. I was expecting that the second command updates j each time it carries out a new calculation. How can I correct this?

(2) ParallelTable actually takes more time than Table. In contrast, when I execute the example in the official document,

```
Table[PrimeQ[x], {x, 10^1000, 10^1000 + 5000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelTable[PrimeQ[x], {x, 10^1000, 10^1000 + 5000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The parallel version does save much time (5.87s vs 3.40s). What could be the reason for ParallelTable to be slower? Does it matter that the function GaussianPotential comes from a separate package I wrote?

Comment: A common reason why parallel operation might be slower is the overhead  of transferring data between kernels.

Comment: @Sascha Thanks! But for the computations I did, Table takes 110 seconds, while ParallelTable takes 113 seconds, which in my regard is not a trivial calculation at each step. Is the overhead still significant in such cases?

Comment: The first run of the parallel kernels takes a lot of time. So, `AbsoluteTiming`will show you the correct results just if you have initiated the kernels preliminary or in case when you run `ParallelTable` at second time..

Comment: Have you tried to remove the j++; and the monitoring part? SetSharedVariable will require all the kernel to synchronize on that variable. Since j is used and modified in all the kernels, this variable will dramatically slow down the parallel computation. Please see the first example in the Possible Issue of the SetSharedVariable[] in the Mathematica document.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but it may help to illustrate some of this behavior.  If I run the simple example,

```
Dynamic[Refresh[TableForm[{"ind2=", ind2, "j=", j}], UpdateInterval -> 1]]

j = 0; num = 100; SetSharedVariable[j]; 
ParallelTable[ind2^2; Pause[2]; j++, {ind2, 1, num}]
```

I find that Dynamic does not display `ind2`.  It does, however, display `j`, which increases in steps of `4` on my four-processor machine.  The `AbsoluteTiming` is `50.2`

On the other hand, with `ParallelTable` replaced by `Table`, both variables display, increasing in steps of `1`.  Here, `AbsoluteTiming` is `200.5`.  Thus, `ParallelTable` is four times as fast here, as expected.

Evidently, the OP finds `ParallelTable` slow, because it is moving large amount of data, as suggested by Sascha.

The actual `ParallelTable` output of this example is

```
{0, 4, 8, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 1, 5, 9, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 2, 
 6, 10, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 36, 
 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 65, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 64, 38, 42, 
 46, 50, 54, 58, 62, 66, 39, 43, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 69, 73, 77, 
 81, 85, 89, 93, 97, 68, 72, 76, 80, 84, 88, 92, 96, 70, 74, 78, 82, 
 86, 90, 94, 98, 71, 75, 79, 83, 87, 91, 95, 99}
```

showing that `ParallelTable` assigns blocks of nine calculations at a time to each of the kernels in this case.  `Method` can be used to specify how the computation of the table is distributed, and this sometimes affects timing.

Of course,

```
j = 0; num = 100; SetSharedVariable[j]; 
ParallelTable[Pause[2]; j++; ind2, {ind2, 1, num}]
```

simply returns a list of 1 to 100, as it should.